# Developing Umbraco with Visual Studio - best practices

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have two environments that use Umbraco: Live and Dev.

As I have in research, Umbraco will be create a physical file when a user creates a new partial view, macro, etc. so, I have two questions:

**1. What is the best way to know which files were created on Live and how to migrate them to Dev environment for the purpose of creating new features?**

I have tried to Google and found "Hybrid Framework" but it is not up to date and I want to maintain code by myself.

**2. I want to extend Umbraco with my own code. What is the best practice for this? (I do not want to change any code in the original Umbraco Source, just create my own new code)**

As I know, I can create a package for extending code but I just want to know the other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Views, Macros , Templates are .cshtml files, these will not affect your source code. Same is case with css and js files; these will not harm any source code. 
Just copy paste these files in respective folders and reload the nodes in backend. It will work properly.

Other way is you can create a package zip file from developer section where you can export datatypes, content and files, and install it in other environment.